# Python syntax error with try & except

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm testing a FTP script in Python 3 to list the files in a directory path give,  but when I'm trying with `try`/`except` handlers, I'm getting a syntax error.

Below is the script code. Please advise what I'm missing or doing wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/python env
import ftplib
def FtpMirroList():
  ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.example.com")
  ftp.login("lodgy", "pass123")
  ftp.cwd("/my/research/folder")

  files = []
  try:
    files = ftp.nlst()
  except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
    if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
      printi("No files in this directory")
    else:
      raise
  for f in files:
    printi(f)

FtpMirroList()
```

It's raising the below error:

```
  File "./ftplib-example-2.py", line 12
    except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `except ftplib.error_perm as resp:`? (`as` instead of `, `)

Comment: @pycoder you correctly catched it ..thnx

Comment: Python3 changed the exception syntax but the Python3 syntax can be used in Python2. As pycoder wrote use `as` instad the comma. If you wanto multiple exceptions to handle then use `except (exc1, exc2, exc3) as e:`.

Comment: @GáborFekete .. Sure i got it know , currently reading the python 3 error handling..thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/python env` should be `#!/usr/bin/env python`

`except ftplib.error_perm, resp` This synthax is not supported in python3. Replace comma with `as`.

Comment: that's correct .thnx

Comment: @Karn if it helped you please mark answer as accepted so that the question can be marked as resolved.